# Download all webpages of a specific website folder with the id with wget using bash

Tags: bash, wget

I need to download all webpages with images of a specific website folder (/content/). Trying to access the folder gives a 403 error, but all links to the pages are in index. They all share the same pattern "content.php?id=xx" where the 'xx' is any number from two to four digits.

What I thought is to download all website and delete everything but the 'content' folder, which will be very time/bandwith consuming as this is a cronjob and need to be run many times. Other approach would be to write a bash script like:

```
wget -k -p http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id{{x}}
```

How can I put a variable with the wget, assuming it's a bash script, to download all the 'id's pages (maybe using a for loop?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there's an index, ideally you can get `wget` to follow links from the index, but filter on only the URLs you want instead of spidering the whole site.  `curl` can't parse HTML and follow links in it, but `wget` can.

wget has `-A` / `-R` [accept/reject glob expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options), or `--accept-regex` / `--reject-regex`.

```
wget -p -k --recursive --level=1 -A '*/content.php?id=*'  http://www.example.com/content/index.php
```

Tweak the accept pattern as needed to avoid crawling the entire site, but still including what you want.  The way wget uses accept/reject rules for html vs. other file types is somewhat complicated, see the docs (which I linked.  scroll down to the bottom of the section on accept/reject patterns).

---

The easiest way to brute-force fetch is with `curl` instead of `wget`, since it has range expressions.  It will also reuse the same HTTP connection for multiple requests, instead of hammering the server with a new TCP connection for every request.  (`wget` defaults to using HTTP keep-alive, too, but it obviously only works if you put multiple URLs on its commandline, rather than running it separately for each URL).

```
curl -L --remote-name-all --compressed --remote-time --fail 'http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=[00-9999]'
```

Note the single quotes around the URL with the range expression, because you need curl to see it, not have bash treat it as a glob or brace expression.

- `--remote-name-all`: save files with a filename based on the remote name, instead of to stdout.  Older `curl` used to require a `-O` for each url pattern given on the cmdline.
- `-L`: follow redirects (`--location`).
- `--fail`: fail silently on server errors (like 404), instead of saving the ErrorDocument.
- `--compressed`: allow gzip transfer encoding.
- `--remote-time`: set local file timestamps based on remote mod time.

Tested it to see if I got it right, and it looks good:

```
$ curl -L --remote-name-all --compressed --remote-time --fail 'http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=[00-9999]'

[1/10000]: http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=00 --> content.php?id=00
--_curl_--http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=00
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

[2/10000]: http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=01 --> content.php?id=01
--_curl_--http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=01
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

[3/10000]: http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=02 --> content.php?id=02

...

[100/10000]: http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=99 --> content.php?id=99
--_curl_--http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=99
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

[101/10000]: http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=100 --> content.php?id=100
--_curl_--http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=100
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

...
```

Comment: You can also use brace expansion with `wget`, although whether ~10000 URLs will exceed the maximum length of command line is an OS-dependent thing.

Comment: Yup, `wget http://.../content?id={99..9999}` would work, subject to cmdline length limits.  Linux can handle the 500kiB command line from `/bin/echo 'http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id='{99..9999} | wc`, but most other OSes won't.

Comment: Reallly? I thought `ARG_MAX` is 2^17=131072 on Linux. (Update: source code: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/limits.h)

Comment: @4ae1e1: `getconf ARG_MAX`  ->  16777216.  That's 16MiB.  Linux 4.2 x86-64.  (Ubuntu 15.10).

Comment: Yeah, on my vivid box with 3.19.0-30-generic `ARG_MAX` is 2097152. Wonder why that `limits.h` from master branch says 131072...

Comment: Found the explanation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/66730 Since Linux 2.6.23 ... the result of `getconf ARG_MAX` now depends on the stack size and may be different from `ARG_MAX` in `limits.h`.

Comment: @4ae1e1: I assume `limits.h` has the lowest value *any* linux system could have.  If you use it as a compile-time constant, rather than using the runtime value for the system you're running on, you need to use a conservative value that will work on *any* system.

Comment: @Kaka: updated my answer with a way to use wget to crawl only the links you want, since you said there's an index.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok, so I was able to test it now. There's an index but not in the 'content' folder, so the wget above fails. The curl iterates from 00 to 9999 downloading 10000 pages, none of the pages seem to be functional (only html code inside), and the images are not downloaded

Comment: @Kaka: oh, I missed the part of the question where you said with the images they link to.  Can't you just point `wget` at the index, with a `--accept` pattern that matches only what you want?  There's nothing special about them being in the same directory; I just made something up for an example.  You probably need the pattern to match the images, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just check the robots.txt it disallow the folder that contains the images, maybe this blocked the curl requests?

Comment: @Kaka: Curl only downloads what you tell it to.  It doesn't parse the HTML to find links to anything, including images or CSS files.  You need `wget` for that, or to run something locally to get the image URLs out of the HTML that curl downloaded.  I don't think wget fetches and obeys `robots.txt`, although it might have an option to do so.  curl certainly doesn't, since again it just requests exactly the URLs from the cmdline.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for id in $(seq 99 9999); do
    wget -k -p http://www.example.com/content/content.php?id=$id
done
```

This asumes all two to four digit IDs are used, otherwise you'll get lots of errors.

Given more information, there would probably be a better solution to this though.

Comment: `seq` is a non-standard utility (not POSIX). Better use builtin C-style for loop.

Comment: Is it? I never realised that; it was always around when I needed it. But POSIX doesn't talk about `wget` either, or does it?

Comment: `wget` is non-standard either, and is certainly not "always around", e.g., not on vanilla OS X. `wget` can be assumed to be present here because this question is specifically about `wget`... A list of standard POSIX utilities is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/contents.html.

Comment: The point is, better use shell's inherent capabilities when it's present and not particularly hard or verbose. Also, command substitution involves forking and hence is rather expensive. Not that it matters here.

Comment: Oh, by the way someone can surely point you to a system where `seq` doesn't exist. A quick Google reveals that Solaris doesn't come with `seq`.

Comment: Not just forking, but the shell has to save the entire output of `seq` in memory, instead of incrementing a counter with a `for ((id=99 ; id < 9999 ; id++)); do wget; done` loop.  Although **putting multiple URLs onto one `wget` cmdline would also save forks, and allow for HTTP 1.1 connection reuse**.  At least with curl;  I think wget defaults to not using that.